# Make accesible my stack from other threads c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a list of thread like this;

```
Kitchen::Kitchen(double multiplier, size_t cooks, size_t restock) :
    _multiplier(multiplier), _ncooks(cooks), _restock(restock)
{
    Cook *cook;
    std::stack<APizza *> orders;
    this->_ingredients = new Stock();
    this->_ordersNow = 0;
    this->_socket = initControlSocket();

    for (size_t i = 0; i != _ncooks; i++) {
        cook = new Cook(this, this->_multiplier);
        this->_cooks.push_back(std::thread(&Cook::Run, cook));
    }
    dprintf(this->_socket, "%d\r\n", KITCHEN_OPENED);
}
```

i Want to make  the std::stack< APizza *> orders; accessible and usable by all my threads in this->_cooks

Comment: You'll need to pass in a pointer to it. You'll also need to ensure this function *does not terminate* until those threads are done.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your threads may need a way to synchronize access to the stack, using a [mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) for example, so you need to pass a reference to a mutex as well.

Have `Cook::Run` accept these arguments by reference:

```
void Run(std::mutex &, std::stack<APizza *> &);
```

Then pass a reference to them when you create the thread:

```
this->_cooks.push_back(std::thread(
    &Cook::Run, cook,
    std::ref(orders_mutex),
    std::ref(orders)
));
```

---

As mentioned by others in the comment section, the stack will be destroyed when control leaves the `Kitchen` constructor. To prevent this, you could make the stack a data member of `Kitchen`.

Alternatively, since you need a mutex on this stack to synchronize concurrent access, you could create a wrapper class that holds the stack and the mutex, and guards access to the stack using the mutex.

```
template <typename T>
class threadsafe_stack {
public:
    void push(T value) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mutex};
        stack.push(std::move(value));
    }

    std::optional<T> pop() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mutex};
        if (!stack.empty()) {
            T val{std::move(stack.top())};
            stack.pop();
            return val;
        }
        return {};
    }

private:
    std::stack<T> stack;
    std::mutex mutex;
};
```

Comment: thanks, if i just do some push(), pop(), top() on the elements on the stack do i need a mutex you think?

Comment: @freeinternet Yes. The standard library containers aren't thread-safe (except for const methods, and only when _only_ const methods are being invoked).